# Looking to modify a Wordpress theme to include home page header image similar to Quartz

Tags: php, css, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am a big fan of how Quartz's site works (please visit qz dot com).

I found the Independent Publisher theme, where the author's GitHub page can be found here...
https://github.com/raamdev/independent-publisher

The theme includes the ability to auto-set a featured image as a post cover, with the post title overlaying the post cover (featured image).

In addition, as with most Wordpress themes, a function of the theme is to place the most recent post at the top of the home page. But I would like that first post to be the header image with overlaying title, linking to the full post, like what Quartz does. The second most recent post would then become the first post in the main content area of the home page.

I hope I am explaining myself clearly enough. I am unable to post more than one link or I would include others to help visualize what I am after.

I am able to do simple theme modifications but nothing like this. Please let me know if this looks possible or if too much work is required to pull it off.

I appreciate any help you can offer.

As a side note, I did contact the developer and asked if he would be interested in incorporating this or helping me modify the theme for my use, but he said he has not received any requests like mine, thus didn't want to take the time to do it, which I understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can search in wordpress support. Check this [styling-the-first-post-differently-from-the-rest](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/styling-the-first-post-differently-from-the-rest)